# Conditional, How I can automate the operation?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, conditional-statements, each

I need that my code can evaluate the value of a few cells and I don't need to change the cell for each answer

I want this process will be automatic

I try with for, but it doesn't work

```
Sub Test()
If Range("E5").Value <> "OK" Or Range("F5").Value <> "OK" Or Range("G5").Value <> "OK" Then
    Range("h5").Value = "NOT ACEPT"
ElseIf Range("E5").Value = "NOT OK" And Range("F5").Value = "NOT OK" And Range("G5").Value = "NOT OK" Then
    Range("H5").Value = "ACEPT"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What kind of `For` did you try? Does your code return an  error? If yes, what error and on which row? If not, does it return something else then what you need?

Comment: Even if all are ok  your H5 will be not accept... Please check my answer below and modify your code

Comment: I have 3 conditions to obtain credit:   
Credit  
1 2 3
Ok Not ok Ok
Not ok Ok Not ok
Ok Ok Ok

I want to check the 3 conditions to determine if the client can obtain the credit

Comment: is it ok?... I also wonder when we put three consecutive conditions in if either in combination of ANDs or ORs why doesnt the vba evaluates such conditions. So, I prefer to use worksheetfunction.or

Comment: Are you sure that you want to obtain "ACEPT" when the three analyzed cells value is "NOT OK"?

Comment: in H5:  `=IF(COUNITIF(E5:G5, "OK") = 3, "ACCEPT", "NOT ACCEPT")`

Comment: thank you. How can I automatize this code for other rows? I don't want to change manually the cell "E5 F5 G5" The next row will be "E6 F6 G6"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub test()

If WorksheetFunction.Or(UCase(Range("E5")) <> "OK", UCase(Range("F5")) <> "OK", UCase(Range("G5")) <> "OK") Then
Range("h5").Value = "NOT ACCEPT"
Else
Range("H5").Value = "ACCEPT"
End If
End Sub
```

If you just want to make cell H5 "accept" or "not accept" you dont need vba you can just do it with a formula and copy it till last cell in H column

IF(AND(UPPER(E5)="OK",UPPER(E5)="OK",UPPER(E5)="OK"),"Accept","Not Accept")

if you need vba then modify the above code to meet your requirement of multiple rows in H column

```
Sub test()
Dim lastrow, cell As Range

lastrow = Cells(1048576, 7).End(xlUp).Row

' not fill the formula from H5 to the last row

For Each cell In Range("H5:H" & lastrow)
    If WorksheetFunction.Or(UCase(cell.Offset(0, -3)) <> "OK", UCase(cell.Offset(0, -2)) <> "OK", UCase(cell.Offset(0, -1)) <> "OK") Then
    cell = "NOT ACCEPT"
    Else
    cell = "ACCEPT"
    End If

Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, how can I automatize this code for other rows? I don't want to change manually the cell "E5 F5 G5" The next row will be "E6 F6 G6"

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: ok so you may not need vba... a simple worksheet formula may be enough

Comment: say you enter in H5 this formula `=IF(AND(UPPER(E5)="OK",UPPER(E5)="OK",UPPER(E5)="OK"),"Accept","Not Accept")` ... then ... you can just copy that formula on all rows down